# Highlight special dates in calendar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, calendar

I have a built a basic calendar using JavaScript. I want to display specific dates in a different color, font or some distinguishing shape  around the date in the calendar. These specific dates are taken from a file (`example.json`).

The below example shows a json with two dates (`2022-04-10` and `2022-05-11`). Ideally, I would have scores of dates and would like to loop over the dates and highlight those in the calendar.

I am very new at JavaScript. I could test that the `index.html` file functions properly. But, it doesn't have the functionality to highlight the said dates.

I checked [this useful website](https://twiki.org/p/pub/TWiki06x01/DatePickerPlugin/doc/html/reference.html#node_sec_1.2) for highlighting dates on calendars in JavaScript. It hasn't worked yet for me.

**How can I highlight the dates which I have in `example.json` in my calendar?**

Following are the files that I have:

**1. index.html**

```
<div class="calendar">
  <span class="month"></span>
  <span class="year"></span>
  <div class="week-days">
    <b>Sun </b><b>Mon </b><b>Tue </b><b>Wed </b><b>Thur </b><b>Fri </b><b>Sat </b>
  </div>
  <div class="days"></div>
  <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</div>
<br />
Select a date to reset calendar
<input type="date" onchange="showCalendar((new Date(this.value)))" />
```

**2. js/example.json**

```
{
    "event1": {
        "name": "Event-1",
        "country": "USA",
        "tasks": [
            "hiking",
            "trekking",
            "jogging"
        ],
        "date": "2022-04-10T01:42:28.533Z"
    },
    "event2": {
        "name": "Event-2",
        "country": "Australia",
        "tasks": [
            "swimming",
            "soccer",
            "baseball"
        ],
        "date": "2022-05-11T01:42:28.533Z"
    }
}
```

**3. js/index.js**

```
import myJson from "./example.json" assert{type: "json"}

console.log(myJson.event);

DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
String string1 = console.log(myJson.event.date);
Date result1 = df1.parse(string1);
```

Comment: Do you mean to say JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: Yes, I meant JavaScript. I am updating the psot. :)

Comment: You seem to be using UTC timestamps. Trivially you can just match on the first 10 characters, which is the date component. However, that's the UTC date, is that what you need, or local date?

Comment: `DateFormat df1 = ...` is not valid javascript.